# ¿Como editar dos o más nodos a la vez en Firebase (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto, el caso es que creo un nuevo Post, al momento de crear un Post los datos que le envio a la Base de datos se guardan en diferentes nodos utilizando updateChildren(), los datos se envian a "posts" y "user-posts"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el codigo Java tengo (NewPostActivity)

```
private void newPost(String userId, String username, String title, String body, String phone, String email, String categoria) {
    // Crear nueva publicación en /user-posts/$userid/$postid y en
    // /posts/$postid simultaneamente
    String key = dtbLocation.child("posts").push().getKey();

    Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body, email, phone, categoria);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key + "/" , postValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

    dtbLocation.updateChildren(childUpdates).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(EditPostActivity.this, "Los datos se guardaron en la BD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Mi duda es como implemento el updateChildren() para editar los datos en los distintos nodos, tengo conocimiento de como editar (sobrescribir) los datos con el setValue(), pero con respecto a updateChildren() no tengo tanto conocimiento

Answer (score 0):

`dtbLocation` hace referencia al nodo **posts**, cuando haces lo siguiente

```
dtbLocation.updateChildren(childUpdates).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(EditPostActivity.this, "Los datos se guardaron en la BD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

estas atachando un listener para saber cuando los datos fueron actualizados, en el momento que los datos fueron actualizados, podes lanzar un segundo listener anidado a la otra referencia para cambiar los datos de esa referencia, y mover tu lógica al ultimo listener, asi vas a saber cuando se termino de escribir en ambos

```
dtbLocation.updateChildren(childUpdates).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
          dtbLocation2.updateChildren(childUpdates).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(EditPostActivity.this, "Los datos se guardaron en la BD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
          });
        }
      });
```

Donde `dtbLocation2` es la referencia al segundo nodo